# Dynamic Basic Block vs Static Basic Blocks and Branching

Tags: compiler-construction, virtual-machine, interpreter

In the book "Virtual Machines" by Smith & Nair (on page number 57), it is described [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=JPhQw41vD2MC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA57#v=onepage&q&f=true) (in context of interpretation & dynamic binary translation), that dynamic basic blocks have branch target in the middle of them, while static basic blocks have not. Static basic block has only single entry and single exit point, as shown in this figure: [static vs dynamic basic blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChDjt.jpg)

Now, on the page number 58 of that book, it is said that complication occurs to the translation process when branch goes to middle of the block that is already translated. Emulation Manager can not get target address as it has only starting address of particular translated block, not the branch target which is inside somewhere in the translated block. So that source code is translated again, even if it is already translated. Solution is to use extra data structure to keep track of the address ranges for each translated block. But **this apparent complication does not occur when dynamic basic blocks are used.**

But, as we can see from the figure and book linked above, the dynamic basic blocks may have branch targets in the middle of them while static blocks do not have such multiple entries. So, how can the dynamic basic block solve that problem instead of static block ?

Thank you in advance...

Edit : In the figure linked above, in the dynamic basic block, there are multiple labels with same name i.e. loop and skip. So, how can interpreter decides which label is actual target ? Is it possible to have multiple labels with same name in same assembly code portion ?

Comment: I do not have and have not read this book, but it seems to me that "dynamic basic block" is a very poor term for this, because as that section shows, it's not a basic block at all. It may be dynamic but it's not basic. That would be like saying "pure chocolate ice-cream" when it's actually a mix of chocolate and strawberry. It may be pure, but it's not chocolate.

Comment: @torek I didn't get you. What do you mean by "dynamic block is not a basic block at all". Can you please explain ?

Comment: A basic block is a block with one entry and one exit. [That's the *definition* of a basic block.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) They seem to say "we translated a block, and *called* it a basic block, and then we found it wasn't basic, so now we slap another word on the front instead of removing the adjective *basic* like we should."

Comment: @torek Thank you. Book authors are calling a block dynamic when it is determined by actual control flow. Dynamic block starts immediately after branch or jump instruction and ends at next branch or jump instruction regardless jump/branch targets are encountered or not within that block.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the problem they want to solve with the dynamic block structure is that when translating as you go it is impossible to determine if an instruction is a branch target and should be at the start of a basic block. The labels are usually not visible in the translated instruction stream.

The idea is that during execution, when you fall into or jump to an address that has not yet been translated you translate everything up to the next expected change in control flow, i.e. the next branch. If you encounter a jump into the middle of an already translated block the simplest approach is to see it as a new dynamic block. This will result in extra code being generated but in general this is not a problem.